# Windows 8 Boot Camp Control Panel on MacBook Air

Tags: windows-8, boot-camp

After getting my hands on a copy of Windows 8, I ran Boot Camp Assistant on my Macbook Air in Mac OS X, and split my drive to install Windows 8.

The installation went without a hitch, but now my trackpad and audio are not working, and I can't run the setup for Boot Camp Control Panel to install. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. Here are the steps I took:

1. Go into Mac OS X and create a fresh driver disc for Windows 7
2. After installing Windows 8, copy the files from the Boot Camp driver disc onto your Windows 8 partition
3. Download Orca, an MSI editor from here: http://www.technipages.com/download-orca-msi-editor.html
4. Use Orca to open up BootCamp64.msi. Delete the conditions out of from the section called "LaunchConditions". Tools -> Options, find the Database tab on the right. Check the box for “Copy embedded streams during Save As”.
5. Save your modified MSI with Orca.

You can now run your modified BootCamp64.msi on Windows 8 and everything will install as expected. After rebooting, you can use the Boot Camp Control Panel in the task bar to modify your keyboard and trackpad settings.

Windows 8 runs like a dream on my MacBook Air! Here's a pic:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this Kirk - I've been looking for hints on 64 bit installs which a few people seem to have had trouble with

Answer (score 2):

this is an excerpt from a tutorial on how to get you windows 8 working on bootcamp

> Press Cmd+E and select the USB drive from the list of drives. Go into the WindowsSupport folder and run Setup. It will install the right graphics drivers and support for the trackpad etc based on your machine.

you can read the whole article [here](http://www.pocket-lint.com/news/45898/how-to-install-windows-8-on-a-mac)